# Getting ValueError when using pandas lambda with multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: python, pandas

When executing the code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def somef(t,y,u):
# Some silly function but close enough to represent actual use case
    y=t+u+y
    g=1*u*t
    l,o=y[0],g[0]
    return l,o
data=np.array([4,6,1,3])

df=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3,4],b=[3,6,4,1]))
df[['ttt','uuu']]=df.apply(lambda x: somef(data,x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
```

The compiler return an error

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

May I know what is the issue?

Expected output

```
a   b   ttt uuu
1   3   8   12
2   6   12  24
3   4   11  16
4   1   9   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `apply` have an argument `result_type`. Assigning the `result_type` equal to `expand` resolve the issue.

> ‘expand’ : list-like results will be turned into columns.

Such that,

```
df[['ttt','uuu']]=df.apply(lambda x: somef(data,x['a'],x['b']), axis=1,result_type="expand")
```

Return

```
   a  b  ttt  uuu
0  1  3    8   12
1  2  6   12   24
2  3  4   11   16
3  4  1    9    4
```

Interesting enough, setting the output column as `df['ttt','uuu']` and the `result_type` as `None` (which is the `default value`)

```
df['ttt','uuu']=df.apply(lambda x: somef(data,x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
```

Return

```
   a  b (ttt, uuu)
0  1  3    (8, 12)
1  2  6   (12, 24)
2  3  4   (11, 16)
3  4  1     (9, 4)
```